# How to implement getters/setters in a MVC project?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, getter-setter

I have a simple question that I couldn't find any answer on the internet (probably because it's obvious).
When you're working on a MVC project, with a OOP language, the correct part to implement getters/setters components is the Model, the Controller, or both of them? 
A Controller has a Model and is used as an interface for Associations, right? That's what's bothering me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my experiance of C# ASP.NET MVC,

The Controller is the area where all you data is retrieve from the query strings and where you handle data from the user

The Model is where all you classed and logic is handled, so a list or variable would reference the model which is where you can add things like functions and data annotations.

The View is where you controller is referencing to. So if you set          Public ActionResult Index() { Return View(); }

within the controller then it will try to return the view corresponding with the name and in this case Index.

Comment: Hi sorry edited the above post but that's for C#, i'm a JAVA programmer but sadly never done MVC with it. Although as far as i'm aware the principals are in essence the same thing.